# How could i make my flask form responsive?

Tags: html, css, deployment, responsive-design, flask-wtforms

[image]I am making my own simple website. With a prebuilt template and the help of chatgpt i managed to make it look as i want since my css knowledge is just basic. But i strugle making my form responsive in all devices

```
<div class="main-banner header-text" id="top">
  <div class="Modern-Slider">
    <div class="item item-3">
      <div class="img-fill">
        <div class="text-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="signup-form-wrapper" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8); padding: 20px; border-radius: 10px; height: 500px; overflow-y: auto; margin-top: 50px;">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <h6 style="color: #a4c639;">Αξιολογηση Επενδυτικου προφιλ</h6>
                  </div>
                  <form action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method="POST" class="question-form">
                    {{ question_form.hidden_tag() }}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="not_member_name">{{ question_form.not_member_name.label }}</label>
                        {{ question_form.not_member_name(class_='form-control') }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="not_member_email">{{ question_form.not_member_email.label }}</label>
                        {{ question_form.not_member_email(class_='form-control') }}
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="not_member_phone">{{ question_form.not_member_phone.label }}</label>
                        {{ question_form.not_member_phone(class_='form-control') }}
                      </div>
                    {% for i in range(1, 8) %}
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="question{{ i }}">{{ question_form['question' ~ i].label }}</label>
                        {{ question_form['question' ~ i](class_='form-control', id='question' ~ i) }}
                        {% for error in question_form['question' ~ i].errors %}
                          <span class="error">{{ error }}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                      {{ question_form.submit(class_='btn btn-primary', style='background-color: #a4c639; border-color: #a4c639;') }}
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]